# How can i add variable in function

Tags: php, function

How can i add variable data in function

```
$accesToken = "EAAAAUaZA8jlABAOoCy9Wy..........";
    $fields = "fields=title,length,from,description,created_time,source";  
    function facebook(){
         $json_array = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/$PID[$FID]/videos?{$fields}&limit=10&access_token={$accesToken}");   
    }
```

Please solution this correct code

Comment: Learn about Scope. This will help with your question. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Pass then in or define them as constants.

Comment: While now edited out, your access token is still visible to the public in the edit history. You need to change/revoke that token **immediately**.

Comment: Pass them as parameters `function facebook($token, $fields) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

```
  $AccessToken = "EAAAAUaZA8jlABAOoCy9Wy58ONRie2TwU697ajMboXCx0OIAe1a8r0E89NN6ZCNRLWMzHgEbhaDVMpYqXiW42aixSjajwGVV1BJM26IIuNkZALrN2NBvFt0fxgmqCYvniZAMEO2SY7v6CstT3OECtDjwBVnku4OgZD";

  function video(){

      global $AccessToken;

        $json_array = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/456898118003430/videos?fields=title,length,from,description,created_time,source&limit=10&access_token=$AccessToken");

    $json_data=json_decode($json_array,true);

   echo "<pre>";

   print_r($json_data);

  }

 video();
```